# need servicenow response decrypted format

Tags: web-services

i have got servicenow webservice response...using below url https://shopko.service-now.com/change_request.do?XML&sysparm_query=state=-5..

i got the response in the form of XML..

But here i want to display  tag value  in my application..But it is coming with encrypted format as highlighted above. Could someone please explain how it can be encrypted..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: <assigned_to>10e8564b6fe32100fa2b122cbb3ee430 </assigned_to>

Comment: since that link is password protected, you will need to post the XML as part of the question

Answer (score 0):

That's not encryption.... that's the sysid of the user record that the assigned to refers to.